# Tracking Spacetime Events

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In the linked post: [Liouville's Theorem For Spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413425/), I indicated the need for tracking the evolution of spacetime events. Is it sufficient to track a spacetime event by placing a particle there with zero initial velocity? You would then identify the spacetime event with the location of the particle. It would need to be a particle with zero mass, so that it could respond to the changes in curvature as quickly as possible. This however runs into trouble with my condition of zero initial velocity.

This seems like a natural choice, since the only way you can measure a spacetime event is by placing a particle there. But without the notion of particles, the notion of spacetime events and how they "move" becomes ambiguous in my mind.

Comment: If you could define 'zero initial velocity' then you could do this.  But you can't.  An event in spacetime is simply a point in the manifold and as such is generally a point on a continuum of timelike geodesics, each of which is the world-line of some particle under the influence of gravity alone.

Comment: Also spacetime can rotate, but you may not be able to detect the rotation with a point-like particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a spacetime is globally hyperbolic, it can be foliated by timelike geodesics, ie it is possible that through each point of the spacetime passes a free particle such that no two such particles ever intersect (this can be shown by using the [Hamiltonian flow](https://arxiv.org/ftp/gr-qc/papers/0211/0211066.pdf) of a Cauchy surface). It can indeed be a way to track spacetime events, although a more important method to do this in the practical case is the intersection of null geodesics with timelike curves - a light ray bouncing between different objects, as this is the most common way to define distances in relativity.

I'm not sure if the global hyperbolicity condition is necessary, but I feel like it might run into some difficulties for instance on the [Carter spacetime](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07947).

Comment: Note (for the questioner) that what this says is *not* that *no* timelike geodesics intersect each other, which is obviously false, merely that you can find sets of them which don't.  In many (all?) cases you can find very many such sets, of course: consider the world-lines of free particles passing through some timelike surface in Minkowski space, for instance.